# cannot get the value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea why I could not get the value from mysql via php in HTML, can you please tell me what's wrong with my coding below, thanks!  this is very strange that I can get the value 1 when I echo $count2 but I could not get the field value no matter echo $bu2 or $dept2, the result of `die("123". $bu2 ." ". $count2 ."123");` is 123   1123

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
include 'db.php';
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $conn);
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT bu, SUBSTRING_INDEX(dept, '-',-1) AS Department FROM tb_user WHERE username = '". $sessionusername ."'", $conn);
$count2=mysql_num_rows($query2);
if ($count2 == 1) {
    $bu2=$query2['bu'];
    $dept2=$query2['Department'];
    die("123". $bu2 ." ". $count2 ."123");
}
mysql_close($conn);}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and assign it to variable, e.g. `$rec`, then use `$rec['bu']`
Full code would be

```
$rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)
$bu2 = $rec['bu'];
$dept2 = $rec['Department'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **mysql_fetch_assoc** to get the values in the array of all values.

```
$connection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

$query = mysql_db_query($database, $query);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

If you check the value of $row you can get the values which type of result you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

While you are trying to use the result of mysql_query as if it was an associative array. In the link I gave you, you can find the correct way of fetching the results of mysql_query. Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo $row['bu'];
}
```

Alternately you can use mysql_fetch_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)
print $data['bu']
```

Just keep in mind both of those functions are deprecated, you'd want to look into mySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to fetch the table rows with

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

Something like:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$bu2 = $row['bu'];
$dept2=$row['Department'];
```